# Around the world cost distance analysis for shipping routes: routing on the other side of the planet

Tags: qgis, routing, least-cost

For cartographic purposes I'd like to calculate routes of cargo-vessels from selected ports around the globe.
The approach I wanted to take was:

1. Create global cost raster, where land is impassable (high price) and water easily passable (low price)
2. Update cost raster with preferential paths (even cheaper to go then 'regular water')

The way I've set it up, starting from any port in Africa/Europe, that would work fine I assume, but starting in Asia/Oceania/Americas the route would still go through the Atlantic and Indian Ocean, as in a planar look of the world, the pacific is split in half. I guess I could tinker with two or even three differently centered maps, but perhaps anyone has a simpler solution? Preferably, I'd like to do this in QGIS.

The situation is described in the two following images. (The large dot is showing Piraeus and New York, respectively while the smaller dots are showing the ports vessels sail to from Piraeus and New York. The lines indicate preferential routes):
[image: From Piraeus all routes would be found easily]
From Piraeus all routes would be found easily
[image: From New York routes would take the detour over the Atlantic and Indian Ocean instead of going through the Pacific]From New York routes would take the detour over the Atlantic and Indian Ocean instead of going through the Pacific.

Comment: Please do not solicit solutions in multiple platforms -- it violates the One question per Question policy.